# View Select a background image and draw on it

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have created a class that extends `View`. I am drawing on it. It works as expected. Now I wanna select an image from Gallery and set it to draw above it.
I am setting the image to the bitmap of the canvas once it is selected.

```
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
mdb.mExtraBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

`mdb` is the object of the that custom `View`.

Here is the `onSizeChanged` method of the `View`.

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
   super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
   mExtraBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
   mExtraCanvas = new Canvas(mExtraBitmap);
   mExtraCanvas.drawColor(WHITE);
}
```

And here is the code inside `onDraw` method

```
super.onDraw(canvas);
canvas.drawBitmap(mExtraBitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

In the `onTouchEvent` method drawing paths on the `mExtraCanvas`.
The problem are.
1. The image is set but cannot draw on it.
2. Scale the image to cover.
Thanks!

Comment: why are you set `mExtraCanvas.drawColor(WHITE);` ?

Comment: Because initially I want it to be white.

Comment: After taking bitmap on canvas, If you draw color then bitmap can't be shown. Try my Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to draw the selected image on `mExtraCanvas`

```
mdb.mExtraCanvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null)
```

And for the scaled part create a scaled bitmap like.

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 
mdb.mExtraBitmap.getWidth(), 
mdb.mExtraBitmap.getHeight(), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Not Tested. But should be work.**

Actually What happen, After set `mdb.mExtraBitmap` , **onSizeChanged** called. And new bitmap created by `Bitmap.createBitmap`.

change `onSizeChanged()` method by below.

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mExtraBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mExtraBitmap,w, h,false);
    mExtraCanvas = new Canvas(mExtraBitmap); 
}
```

And no need to draw bitmap again since you are making canvas from Bitmap.

Use `mExtraCanvas` for every drawing instead of other `canvas`.

Comment: Yes I am drawing on mExtraCanvas and later drawing that extra bitmap only in the onDraw of the View. Thanks but it didn't help me.

Comment: So, add full implementation for more clarification.

Comment: "no need to draw bitmap again" You will not see the drawings if you don't draw the extra bitmap. Lemme remind you that it is the extra bitmap that I am drawing on. Using it to save the previous drawings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185348/discussion-between-abhay-koradiya-and-maseed).